# How does YouTube and Netflix push content to Roku?

Tags: youtube, netflix, roku

Using a mobile app, it is possible to "Cast" media from your mobile app to a Roku device on the same network.  I do not understand the mechanism being used which allows a remote device (YouTube Android app for example) to cause  the selected Roku to open the YouTube channel and start playing the video.
I have looked though the Roku developer documentation and am unable to locate any way to launch a channel without the user choosing that channel.

Comment: So you're asking "How can I push content to Roku _programmatically_ (like Youtube and Netflix does)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

1. Use the [External Control
   API](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+API#ExternalControlAPI-SSDP(SimpleServiceDiscoveryProtocol))
   to discover the Roku device(s).
2. Use the
   [query/apps](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+API#ExternalControlAPI-query/apps)
   command to ensure that the app you're targeting is installed
   and/or to obtain the app id. You could also use the
   [install/appID](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+API#ExternalControlAPI-install/appID)
   command if you know the app id and you discovered that the app is
   not installed.
3. Use the
   [launch/appID](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+API#ExternalControlAPI-launch/appID)
   to open the app and deep link to specific content. The url should
   look something like this
   `http://<device-ip>:8060/launch/<your-app-id>?contentId=<movie-id-in-your-api>&mediaType=movie`.
   Quick note, the `install/appID` command also launches the app after
   it's installed the same way the `launch/appID` command would.
4. Handle the deep link in your Roku app.

Example:

```
sub main(args as dynamic)
  contentID = args.contentID
  mediaType = args.mediaType
  if contentID <> invalid and mediaType <> invalid
    // Either store the parameters for later use in the app, or make the 
    // requests to your content API right here.
  end if
end sub
```

More details on Deep Linking [here](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Deep+Linking).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [Alejandro Cotilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1792699/alejandro-cotilla) answer, You can check some simple implementation of the [External Control API](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+API#ExternalControlAPI-SSDP(SimpleServiceDiscoveryProtocol)) here on [this repo](https://dev.to/umitic/how-to-launch-a-roku-channel-from-within-another-roku-channel-b6f).